# Get Page Creation Date from Facebook API

Tags: javascript, python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been successfully able to get page lists, extract data, and more from the Facebook API in both Python and JavaScript, but oddly I'm getting stuck on something that seems like it should be simple!

I found [the documentation for retrieving a page's creation date through the Facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page-start-info/).

However, I have tried every which way to get this to work and I keep getting errors.

In their [graph explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/), I tried

```
{page-id}?fields=date
{page-id}?fields=day
{page-id}?fields=month, day, year
{page-id}?fields={fieldname_of_type_PageStartInfo}
{app-id}?fields=date
{app-id}?fields=day
{app-id}?fields=month, day, year
{app-id}?fields={fieldname_of_type_PageStartInfo}
...?fields=date
...?fields=day
...?fields=month, day, year
...?fields={fieldname_of_type_PageStartInfo}
```

where I replaced {app-id} with my application's ID, and {page-id} with the id of the page I wanted the start date for. Where it says "..." I literally left in "...". Where it says {fieldname_of_type_PageStartInfo} I literally put that in, including the brackets (I knew this was probably wrong but was getting desperate and tried everything!)

All of these combinations returned various errors including:

```
     "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (day) on node type (Application)",
    "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: ...",
"message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (day) on node type (Page)",
```

I'd prefer a solution in JavaScript, Python, or just the URL that would go in the Graph API Explorer if possible. Thank you!

Comment: File a bug on https://developers.facebook.com/bugs because that page is wrong.

Comment: Will do, thanks @WizKid!

Comment: Bug is here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/144317056242507/